# adding each row value from different table

Tags: php, mysql

Problem:
3 tables: tbl_product, tbl_soldproducts, tbl_purchasedetail
tbl_product has a primary key of prod_no which is foreign key on each of the 2 table.
tbl_products
[image: tbl_products]
tbl_purchasedetail
[image: tbl_purchasedetail]
tbl_soldproducts
[image: tbl_soldproducts]

In tbl_soldproducts I have column item_sold describe how many items sold for this product per transaction.
In tbl_purchasedetail I have qty_purchase which describe as number of item purchase per transaction.
I need to count the total item sold and purchase per product.
Ex output:

```
Prod no | item_sold |qty_purchase | left
   1    |    23     |     25      |  2
   2    |    1      |     10      |  9
```

My current code which display wrong output:

```
   SELECT TP.prod_no,TP.barcode,TP.prod_name, COUNT(TS.qty) as num_sold,
   COUNT(TPS.qty_delivered) as num_delivered
   FROM tbl_product AS TP 
   LEFT JOIN tbl_soldproducts AS TS
   on (TS.prod_no = TP.prod_no)
   LEFT JOIN tbl_purchasedetail AS TPS
   on (TPS.prod_no = TP.prod_no)
   group by TS.prod_no
   ORDER BY TP.prod_name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never showed us any sample data, but I think you should be aggregating the two auxiliary tables in separate subqueries, and then joining those results back to `tbl_product`.  Something like this should work:

```
SELECT TP.prod_no,
       TP.barcode,
       TP.prod_name,
       COALESCE(TS.num_sold, 0) AS num_sold,
       COALESCE(TPS.num_delivered, 0) AS num_delivered
FROM tbl_product TP
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT prod_no, COUNT(*) AS num_sold
    FROM tbl_soldproducts
    GROUP BY prod_no
) TS
    ON TP.prod_no = TS.prod_no
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT prod_no, COUNT(*) AS num_delivered
    FROM tbl_purchasedetail
    GROUP BY prod_no
) TPS
    ON TP.prod_no = TPS.prod_no
ORDER BY TP.prod_name
```

Your original query might have been OK if all you wanted to select from `tbl_product` was the product number.  But your query could have strange behavior as is, because you are selecting non aggregate columns from `tbl_product` while using `GROUP BY`.  You should go with an approach such as what I suggested instead if you want to also select other columns.

Comment: Thank you. I got it running by changing COUNT to SUM. Now it is adding all the quantity sold and quantity purchase.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better give us a database case. @Tim Biegeleisen That's right

Comment: Hi Jiang, you should leave this as a comment, and if you can't then maybe get some more rep so you can comment.

Comment: Sorry, I do not have enough reputation for append comments, I just used it shortly